# how to legitimate an user of his profile?

Tags: php, authentication, get

i have a problem with $_GET to authenticfiate an owner of his site.

im using this code to check, if the users id is registrated or not:

```
<?php
session_start();

include('scripts/db_connect.php');

    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        $url_auth = $_GET['id'];

    }else{
        echo "no user found";
    exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$url_auth."'";
$query = $db->query($sql);
if($query->num_rows !=1){
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
```

i having problems with reading out that $_GET id. it seems that something is going wrong and i dont know why. is there maybe another way to check for users registration when someone is calling any id in the browser? thanks.

Comment: In this code, `$_GET['id']` will not be checked if they don't have a session variable called 'id'. Is that your intention?

Comment: why do you check the session but the then use $_GET ?

Comment: By the way, you have a big security hole here - SQL injection. Do this instead: `$url_auth = (int) $_GET['id']`.

Comment: hello, yes it seems to be something wrong with that $_GET. it is not reading it out from the url. the problem is, that it will be displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
<?php
session_start();

include('scripts/db_connect.php');

$id=mysql_escape_string($_GET['id']); //Sanitized the variable to avoid SQL Injection attacks

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$id."'";
$query = $db->query($sql);
if($query->num_rows !=1){
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
else
{
$_SESSION["loggedIn"]="Success";
header("authenticationSuccess.php");
}
?>
```

Now check this `$_SESSION["loggedIn"]="Success"` on all your other pages to check whether the user is genuine.

**Changes for Comment:**

If you really think `$_GET` is the problem , try this.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    @extract($_GET);
    include('scripts/db_connect.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".mysql_escape_string($id)."'";
    $query = $db->query($sql);
    if($query->num_rows !=1){
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
    $_SESSION["loggedIn"]="Success";
    header("authenticationSuccess.php");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: hello, thanks for answering. i tried to use that. but im getting forwarded to index.php. it seems that i'm having some difficulties to read out $_GET from the id.

Comment: Just to check .. Why don't you try hardcoding the value to see if your query is performing right ? $sql = SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=whateveryouridis;

Comment: the query is working. that gets the right id. this will be displayed in the url the right way.

Comment: hello and thanks for helping. $GET was the problem. on serverside was enabled mod_rewrite so that the server was not able to read the id. thanks alot.